# TypeError: relatedEntities.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, nestjs, typeorm

I am working on the backend of a project using Nestjs and everything has been okay until now that I found out an endpoint is giving an issue when I tested it on postman. Whenever I try to create using this endpoint, it gives this error: ***"TypeError: relatedEntities.forEach is not a function"***. I have tried my best to fix this but was not successful.

**assessment entity**

```
@Entity()
export class Result {
  //...

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  summary: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Assessment, (assessment) => assessment.result)
  assessments: Assessment[];

  //...
}
```

**result entity**

```
@Entity()
export class Assessment {
  
  //...

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  format: string;


  @ManyToOne(() => Result, (result) => result.assessments)
  result: Result;

//...
}
```

**result repository**

```
@EntityRepository(Result)
export class ResultRepository extends Repository<Result> {
  async createResult(createResultDto: CreateResultDto): Promise<Result> {
    const { name, summary, assessments, comment } = createResultDto;
    const result = new Result();
    result.name = name;
    result.assessments = assessments;
    result.summary = summary;
    result.comment = comment;
    return this.save(result);
//more code...
```

Comment: Can you share the code that has `relatedEntities` in it?

Comment: I don't have any ```relatedEntities``` file. ```relatedEntities``` is not in my code. The problem is related to the ralationship of the entities I used which I have mentioned.